# JavaScript not running when input box is focused on. Simple fix?

Tags: javascript, html

I copied this code from my previous website, which was running perfectly fine. However, even when I copied everything over, it doesn't work for some reason.

I've looked through the code and never touched anything, but also fiddled around with a few options I could have thought of. Nothing has worked so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpbmg0z6/

```
HTML:

<section class="contact__section" id="contact">
    <h2 class="vh">Contact Me</h2>
    <div class="innerContent">
        <div class="contact__form clear all">
            <fieldset id="contact_form">                                            
                <div class="contactForm__full contactForm__input">
                    <label for="name" class="all">name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="contactForm__full contactForm__input">
                    <label for="email" class="all">email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                </div>
                <div class="contactForm__full contactForm__input">
                    <label for="message" class="all">message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="contactForm__full">
                    <button class="submit_btn all" id="submit_btn" aria-label="Submit message">submit</button>
                </div>

                <div id="result" class="contactForm__results"></div>

            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>






JS:

$("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("label").removeClass("labelBlur").addClass("labelFocus");
});
$("input").focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).parent().find("label").addClass("labelBlur").removeClass("labelFocus");
    }
});

var inputs = $("input").length;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
    $input = $("input:eq(" + i + ")");
    if (($input.attr("type") != "checkbox") && ($input.attr("type") != "submit")) {
        if ($input.val().length != 0) {
            $input.parent().find("label").addClass("labelFocus");
        } else {
            $input.parent().find("label").addClass("labelBlur");
        }
    }
}

$("textarea").focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("label").removeClass("labelBlur").addClass("labelFocus--textarea");
});
$("textarea").focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).parent().find("label").addClass("labelBlur").removeClass("labelFocus--textarea");
    }
});

var textareas = $("textarea").length;
for (var i = 0; i < textareas; i++) {
    $textarea = $("textarea:eq(" + i + ")");
    if (($textarea.attr("type") != "checkbox") && ($textarea.attr("type") != "submit")) {
        if ($textarea.val().length != 0) {
            $textarea.parent().find("label").addClass("labelFocus--textarea");
        } else {
            $textarea.parent().find("label").addClass("labelBlur");
        }
    }
}
```

All it's supposed to be doing is when you click/focus on one of the inputs, it adds a class, and when you unfocus, it removes that class and adds back the default class.

Comment: Tip: it's better to include all the relevant code in your question rather than using a JSFiddle. For web development questions you should be able to create a live snippet in the question itself by pressing Ctrl-M from the editor and adding your JS/CSS/HTML in the form that appears.

Comment: Are you sure you still are loading jQuery library ?  Looking at your Fiddle, it seem to work if you just include jQuery.  https://jsfiddle.net/sscotti/spzrkg69/

Comment: It toggles the labelBlur and labelFocus classes.

Comment: Thanks guys, careless mistake of mine. One of my javascript functions from something else was messing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, you've forgotten to include jQuery. Once jQuery is added the code works fine; do you think you've done the same on your actual site?

To add jQuery via a CDN visit https://code.jquery.com/ and pick one of the script tags on offer, e.g.

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Oh you're right. That works in the JSFiddle, although I already have jQuery hooked up on my site. It still has the same problem. Maybe something is disabling or interfering with my jQuery... going to look into it and get back to you if I can't figure out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Got it to work, one of my javascript functions from something else was messing it up.